# PHP - Save image uploaded with AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, file-upload

Given this one a few hours research and thought but I'm not getting anywhere.

I have managed to get an image file to upload through AJAX using a FormData object. When the file reaches the php code I am able to access its info such as `'name'` and `'type'` by using:

```
$_FILES['newFile']['name'];
$_FILES['newFile']['type'];
```

And so on, which means that the file must be uploading as intended, I just can't seem to save it to a file from there.

I have tried:

```
$file = file_get_contents($_FILES["newFile"]['tmp_name']);
imagejpeg($file, '/img/uploads/' . $_FILES["newFile"]['name']);
```

But then imagejpeg gives me the error "Expects paramater1 to be resource, string given."
So I tried:

```
$file = imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($_FILES["newFile"]['tmp_name']));
imagejpeg($file, '/img/uploads/' . $_FILES["newFile"]['name']);
```

I now receive the error: `/"imagejpeg('/img/uploads/image.jpg'): Failed to open stream. No such file or directory."`

Can someone explain how I get the image from the array to a file on disk?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the move_uploaded_file function like this:

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["uploaded_file"]["tmp_name"], $pathfilename)
```

Comment: I had tried this also, I get the same error: "Failed to open stream. No such file or directory." with an additional error: "Unable to move 'C://xampp/tmp/something.tmp' to '/img/uploads/image.jpg'" Could there be an issue with my output path?

Comment: Yes, it could be that you don't have permissions or some other error. But using the move_uploaded_file() function is the way. Stay on that track.

Answer (score 0):

Use php function move_uploaded_file("$_FILES['newFile']['tmp_name']","Location_where_you_want_to_save");

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out! Obviously "/img/uploads/" was the issue. PHP doesn't recognize a forward slash as the root directory! My fault!

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["newFile"]['tmp_name'], $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/img/uploads/' . $_FILES["newFile"]['name']);
```

Using $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] before the new file path worked perfectly.